# Youtube API video descriptions truncated

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I am currently experiencing the problem that the descriptions of the videos coming from the Youtube API are being truncated to 150-160 characters.

It was working correctly and I could get full descriptions for each video that I have found, but for the past 2 weeks the descriptions are truncated. Has anyone experienced the same problem?

This is my query:

```
youtube_instance.search().list(q = query,
                               part = "id, snippet",
                               publishedBefore=str(date_string) + "T23:59:59.000Z",
                               publishedAfter=str(date_string) + "T00:00:00.000Z",
                               type = 'channel, video',
                               maxResults = max_results).execute()
```

Comment: have you fied a bug report?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find anything in the Youtube API forum

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803

Comment: Did you solve the issue?